# "Shared Folders" Feature Is Not Working In VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 11.10 as a host and another linux 2.6 distribution as a guest.

When I try to setup guest additions, this error message appears

```
Building the shared folder support module .. fail
```

And because of that, when I run the following in terminal

```
mount -t vboxsf shared /root/shared
```

I get the following error message

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'vboxsf'
```

Any syggestions please?

**EDIT**

Sorry, the mentioned error message isn't complete, this is it.

```
Building the shared folder support module ...fail!
(Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong)
```

This is the content of vboxadd-install.log

```
    Uninstalling modules from DKMS
    Attempting to install using DKMS

    Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/4.1.2/source ->
                     /usr/src/vboxguest-4.1.2

    DKMS: add Completed.

    Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

    Building module:
    cleaning build area....
    make KERNELRELEASE=3.2.6 -C /lib/modules/3.2.6/build M=/var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/4.1.2/build..........................(bad exit status: 2)

    Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.2.6 (i686)
    Consult the make.log in the build directory
    /var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/4.1.2/build/ for more information.
    0
    0
    ERROR: binary package for vboxguest: 4.1.2 not found
    Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
    make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 -C /lib/modules/3.2.6/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 modules
    test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
        echo;                               \
        echo "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
        echo "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
        echo "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
        echo;                               \
        /bin/false)
    mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*

      WARNING: Symbol version dump /usr/src/linux-source-3.2.6/Module.symvers
               is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.
```

Actually the log file is very large and it exceeds the 30000 characters limit. How can I upload the entire log file here?

Comment: We need more info, Which is that other linux distro?. Are there any extra error messages while installing guest additions?.

Comment: Yes, what he said. Version 2.6 of *which* linux?? It sounds like your problems are related to your VM guest rather than the host OS (Ubuntu). Also, which version of VirtualBox are you using?

Comment: It's called BackTrack (a distro based on Ubuntu).
No extra error messages, every thing is going well except the shared folder support module.

I'm using VirtualBox v4.1.2

Comment: Also after some googling, some suggest to add the user of the guest OS into 'vboxsf' group. Well, there's no group called 'vboxsf'. It should be created automatically after installing the guest additions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it's working now.

It seems that virtualbox version in Ubuntu repository is not updated. The latest version in the repository is v4.1.2 while the latest version offered by the official site is v4.1.12. After installing the latest version, everything is working perfectly. Thanks all.